# How to calculate marginal utility?

Tags: utility, marginal-distribution

I am having some difficulties understanding the calculations of marginal utility.

On this problem (,)= square root of PM

I know that MRS is equal to MUp/MUm but i do not understand how its possible that :

MUp=1 / square root of 10 and

MUm=2.5/ square root of 10

I have some learning disabilities and any clear and simple answer on how to get this values would be greatly appreciated.

I know that MUp is calculated by finding the partial derivative of U with respect to p but where do i get these values to do these calculations? Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can estimate these partial derivatives from the graph by reading the change in $P$ (respectively, $M$) required to reach the next highest labeled indifference curve.  Then
$$
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial P} \approx \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta P}
    \text{ and }
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial M} \approx \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta M}
$$

There isn't enough information in the diagram to show that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}(A) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial M}(A) = \frac{5}{2\sqrt{10}}$, though.  Since $U(2,5) = \sqrt{10}$, I am guessing that $U(M,P) = \sqrt{MP}$ as a definition on another slide.

If that is the case, then you can compute the partial derivatives with the power rule.  $U(M,P) = P^{1/2} M^{1/2}$, so
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial M} &= \frac{1}{2} P^{1/2} M^{-1/2} = \frac{\sqrt{P}}{2\sqrt{M}} \\
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial P} &= \frac{1}{2} P^{-1/2} M^{1/2} = \frac{\sqrt{M}}{2\sqrt{P}} \\
\end{align*}
So at $A = (2,5)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial M}(2,5) &= \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{2}} 
    = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}
    = \frac{5}{2\sqrt{10}} = \frac{2.5}{\sqrt{10}}\\
    \frac{\partial U}{\partial P}(2,5) &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{5}} 
    = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{5}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}
    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}
\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes,  (,)=.  I really appreciate your help, but i am still a bit confused on how to get MU's. Is there a way I can do it algebriacally ?

Comment: I would deeply appreciate it if you could show me the steps

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa  See edits.

Comment: you are a saver thank you so much